# $refs attribute is giving me an empty object when ever a button is been clicked in vue js2

Tags: vue.js

whenever i try to get the value of a ref of my input on my console it returns an empty object.i used the $emit function to pass the function from the child component to the parent component. i tried console.log(this.$refs) and it consoled an empty object and i also tried console.log(this.$refs.input) and it consoled undefined.

```
//this is the child component
<pre>
<template> 
    <form>
      <input type="text" placeholder="Search Movies" v-model="search" ref="input" >
      <button @click.prevent="submit">search</button>//this is the click event
     </form>
    </div>
    <div>    
  </div>
</template>

<script> 
export default { 
   props:['movie'],

  data () {
    return {
        search:'',
        input:'',
    }
  },
  methods: {
   submit() {
     this.$emit('finished');
   }
 }
 }
</script>

<style scoped>

</style>
</pre>

//parent component
<pre>
<template> 
  <div>
  <movie></movie>
  <search :movie='movie' @finished='finished'></search>
  </div>
</template>

<script> 
const key = '17de97b1';
let title= '';
const url = `http://www.omdbapi.com/?i=tt3896198&apikey=*******&t=`;

import movie from './components/movie.vue'
import search from './components/search.vue'
export default {
  components: {
    'movie': movie, 
    'search': search,
  },
  data () {
    return {
     movie: {},
     search: '',
     title:'',
    //  input:'',
    }
  },
   mounted(){
    this.fetchData();
  },


  methods: {
    fetchData: function () {
      this.$http.get(url + title).then(function(data){
      this.movie = data.body;
      console.log(data);
}).catch(err => {
        console.log(error);
      });
},
  finished() {
     console.log(this.$refs);  
    }
},
}
</script>

<style scoped>

</style>
</pre>



i expected that when i click the submit button it would give me the value of the input

   [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/U533B.jpg
```

Comment: you should have an error in your fetchData method

Comment: but the fetchData is working fine

Comment: The parent component does not have any $refs

Answer (score 1):

The `ref` is in the child component, while you are trying to use it in the parent component.

You can pass the input as the event argument if you need it in the parent component.

`this.$emit('finished', this.$refs.input)`

But, I would not do that. If all you want is the value, the pass the value instead.

`this.$emit('finished', this.search)`

Answer (score 0):

I'd advice u use v-model to have two way binding instead of $ref. Also, I don't entirely get what u want to do here. U just want to log what u type into the console, right?

Comment: If you are not sure about your answer so leave a comment. Don't answer